# Vertex texture Fetch (Texture read in vertex shader)

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

New to Opengl and GLSL.

I am using **OpenGL es 3.0** and **my GLSL version #version 300 es**.

i want to get pixel(ARGB data) at every position in my vertex shader(vertex texture fetch). i have verified that my Android tablet supports vertex texture fetch.

Now i pass in the texture(image) and Texture coordinates to the vertex shader
and execute

```
GLES30.glDrawArrays(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Is this the right way or should i use GL_POINTS .
if i am using GL_POINTS how to pass the texture cooordinate?

could you provide any samples/example code that does a full pixel read(ARGB) in the vertex shader.

attaching my vertex shader

```
uniform sampler2D sTexture; 
in vec4 aTextureCoord;
out vec3 colorFactor;
vec2 vTextureCoord;
vec4 tex;
void main() 
{
   vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord.xy;
   tex =  texture(sTexture,vTextureCoord);
   float luminance = 0.299 * tex.r + 0.587 * tex.g + 0.114 * tex.b;
   colorFactor = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
   gl_Position = vec4(-1.0 + (luminance * 0.00784313725), 0.0, 0.0,      1.0); 
   gl_PointSize = 1.0;
};
```

My texture coordinates passed are 
     {0.f,1.f}
     {1.f,1.f}                                                                    {0.f,0.f}
 {1.f,0.f}

and the shader is triggered by

```
GLES30.glDrawArrays(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a sampler and sample it exactly as per usual. E.g.

```
"#version 150\n"

in vec4 position;
in vec2 texCoordinate;

uniform sampler2D texID;
uniform mat4 modelViewProjection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = modelViewProjection * (position + texture(texID, texCoordinate));
}
```

That will sample a 4d vector from the texture unit `texID` at location `texCoordinate`, using that to perturb `position` prior to applying the model-view-projection matrix. The type of geometry you're drawing makes no difference.

Comment: i have verified it using glGet and got 16 for   GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS

Comment: "implementations can declare zero vertex texture units", [Table 6.31 (page 274)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/3.0/es_spec_3.0.4.pdf) says the minimum value for `GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` is 16, not zero.  You might be thinking of ES 2.0 where the minimum was zero ([Table 6.20, page 154](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks for the response :)                                                                      
    

my purpose is to calculate luminous histogram value from the color information in vertex shader
so ,
color = texture(texID,texcoordinate) will it return every pixels in vertex shader?
to get every pixels should i have to use GL_POINTS?
i am new to these things  @Tommy

Comment: @genpfault in that case I can confirm that some ostensible ES 3 implementations are non-conformant. Will edit answer though as you're right, and I'm wrong.

Comment: @vishnudinakaran yes, I guess you could use GL_POINTS, one per pixel in the source, then make the position a function of that to bucket them, then output with an additive blending mode? That is, assuming that clamping of the output doesn't ruin you.

Comment: @genpfault                                                                                                    Thanks :) ,i am using samsung galaxy A tab with adreno 306 gpu .so 16 means that my tab does not support Vertex texture fetch wrt? i did not get any crash while doing a texture read in vertex shader

Comment: @Tommy                                                                                                       The orginal application worked by getting the pixels from gpu by using glreadpixel(very slow operation)
and then passing this information to shader
using GL_POINTS which calculates the histogram.
since i thought if my device supports vertex texture fetch i could do a texture read in vertex shader and avoid the glreadpixel call
so in that case how do i pass my texture coordinate to vertex shader if i am using GL_POINTS

Comment: @vishnudinakaran yes, you should be able to do exactly that; if the rest of the pipeline already works then there definitely should be no problem. You should be fine to read the texture (and up to 15 others), just add the sampler and do all the usual stuff to attach it to a suitable sampler and the sampler to a suitable source.

Comment: @Tommy                                                                                                        Could you have a look at my code,i have editted the question with my vertex shader and texture coordinates. are they correct?

Answer (score -1):

> gl_Position = vec4(-1.0 + (luminance * 0.00784313725), 0.0, 0.0,      1.0);

That's clever. It's not going to *work*, but that's clever.

The thing that is confusing everyone is what you haven't told us. That you're computing the histogram by using blending. That you compute the location for each fragment based on the luminance, so you get lots of overlap. And blending just adds everything together, thus producing your histogram.

FYI: It's always best to explain what it is you're actually trying to accomplish in your question, rather than hoping that someone can deduce what you're attempting to do.

That's not going to work because you only have four vertices in this case. You have lots of fragments, but they will be generated based on interpolation from your 4 vertices. And you can't change the position of a fragment from within a fragment shader.

If you want to do what you're trying to do, you still have to render one vertex for every texel you fetch. You still need to use `GL_POINTS`.

Comment: I have actually used the histogram calculation from an opensource project and have absolutely no idea how the thing works.anyway i am getting the histogram when i am using glreadpixel and passing on the pixel data to the shader as attribute and triggered using
GLES30.glDrawArrays(GLES30.GL_POINT, 0, #no of pixel);
now i wanted to do texture reads in vertex shader to avoid glreadpixel ,in that as you specified i need to use GL_POINT .In that case how do i pass my texture coordinate to read the entire pixel in vertex shader.could you provide any samples/suggestion for this.

Comment: In between is there a better method to calculate luminous histogram in GPU.